# Visual Studio 2015 WPF app publish but no exe found

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, deployment

[image: Visual Studio 2015 publish app]

I publish the WPF app via VS2015, but what I found in server is

```
ubuntu@myip:/home/user/public_ftp/myapp/releases/Application Files/MyApp$ ll
total 1164
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user   4096 Nov 24 10:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 11 user user   4096 Nov 24 10:15 ../ 
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 424448 Nov 24 10:15 MySql.Data.dll.deploy
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 171008 Nov 24 10:15 NAppUpdate.Framework.dll.deploy
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 526336 Nov 24 10:15 Newtonsoft.Json.dll.deploy
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   5803 Nov 24 10:15 MyApp.application
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    189 Nov 24 10:15 MyApp.exe.config.deploy
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  30120 Nov 24 10:15 MyApp.exe.deploy
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  10217 Nov 24 10:15 MyApp.exe.manifest
```

Which don't have **MyApp.exe** file. I have the other Winform app, but publish the **exe** together.

How to publish the **exe** file together in WPF app?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. Is on the **Options...** there

[image: Visual Studio 2015 publish option]

Then uncheck the **Use ".deploy" file extension**

[image: Publish option details]

So now it works